# Combinations - Permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Find the number of ways in which 5 books can be distributed between three people A,B and C, if the books are a)indistinguishable, b)all different.

a) $\displaystyle \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = 10$

b)$ 5\times 4 \times 3 = 60$

Could you check my solutions?

Comment: Your answer $a$ seems to be answering "how many ways can you pick exactly 3 books out of five distinguishable books" (without distributing). Your answer $b$ assumes that each person gets exactly one book.

Comment: I am practicing solving many similar problems, but it takes time to decided what method to choose. For instance, I was thinking of using a formula for combinations, repetition is allowed, so that I am quite confused. Would you be able to state the most important rules? Thank you.

Comment: Some basic problem types and answers added below.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you think of this problem using the **Stars and Bars** approach.

Let $\star$ represent a book, and let $\mid$ represent a divider between people.  Represent an outcome of who gets how many books in the following way: All $\star$'s to the left of the first bar will be given to the first person.  All $\star$'s between the first bar and the second bar are given to the second person.  All $\star$'s after the second bar are given to the third person.  E.g. $\star \star \mid \star \mid \star \star$ corresponds to person $A$ getting two books, person $B$ getting one book, and person $C$ getting two books, whereas $\mid \mid \star \star \star\star\star$ corresponds to person $C$ getting all the books and $A$ and $B$ not getting any.

How many ways are there to arrange the stars and bars?  Think combinations.

---

For part b, consider multiplication principle.  Who gets book 1?  Who gets book 2?  Who gets book 3?...

---

To reply to the question in the comments above: A lot of it comes with practice in being able to reword a problem to match a different problem you have already seen.

- $n^r$ You have $n$ distinguishable objects, all of which being distributed to $r$ distinguishable people.  "How many ways can you distribute 5 different books to 3 different people"
- $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right) = \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$  You have $n$ indistinguishable objects, all of which being distributed to $r$ distinguishable people.  "How many ways can you give 5 identical whole cookies to 3 children"
- $\binom{n}{r}$ You split $n$ objects into two partitions.  One of size $r$ and one of size $n-r$.  "How many ways can you choose 3 people out of a total of 5"
- $\binom{n}{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots,r_k} = \frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!\dots r_k!}$ You split $n$ objects into $k$ partitions, of size $r_1, r_2,\dots, r_k$ respectively.  "How many ways can you rearrange the letters of the word MISSISSIPPI"
- $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ The number of arrangements of $r$ objects from a collection of $n$ distinguishable objects.  "How many ways can first second and third place trophies be given in a race of 10 people"

Many counting problems can fall into one of these categories, though perhaps with a different flavor or may require multiple steps involving multiplication principle, addition principle, or inclusion-exclusion to account for further complexities.  A big part of practice and understanding is trying to reword a problem you are given into one of these forms.

For examples, "How many ways can you rearrange the letters of the word MISSISSIPPI" is just a different flavor of the question "In a room of 11 people, how many ways can you split them into four distinguishable teams of sizes 1,2,4, and 4 respectively"

The "How many ways can you give 5 identical whole cookies to 3 children" is just a different flavor of "How many Diophantine (integer) solutions exist for $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 5$ subject to $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$"